# update state in Test of functionnal Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test my React Functionnal Component using Jest but I'm facing a problem trying to update the state of the component.

Here is my simple component:

```
import {FunctionComponent, useEffect, useState} from "react";

import {LoginForm} from './../form/LoginForm';


import {requestConnexion} from "../../effector/UserEffects";

export const Login: FunctionComponent = () => {


    const [error, setError] = useState("");


    useEffect(()=>{
        return requestConnexion.done.watch(({result, params}) => {
            console.log(result.data);
            userConnected(result.data["token"]);

            // @ts-ignore
            addProfileToStore(result.data["userProfile"]);
            console.log("[LOGIN_PAGE] User connected");
            history.push('/');
        })
    })
    useEffect(()=>{
        return requestConnexion.fail.watch(({error, params}) => {
            console.log(params);
            setErrorToState("Bad credentials");
        })
    })

    const setErrorToState = (error:string) => {
        setError(error);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <LoginForm error={error}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

I've tried to use the function `setState` from enzyme but it's only working with class component ?

Comment: can you provide a more detailed explanation as to what exactly is failing?

Comment: The state is set by requestConnexion, so set it this way, mock it if needed.

Comment: @lucasreta I have the following error: ShallowWrapper::setState() can only be called on a class components